# How to make a test-train split in the table using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am slightly new to PostgreSQL and had a doubt.

Suppose I have a table with data like this (below). How do I select ten rows from each of the classes (or sentiments), i.e. 10 positive tweets, 10 extremely positive tweets, 10 negative tweets, etc. (there are around 11 such classes)? The data is also somewhat large to do manually; ~1k rows.

As the title reads, my actual goal is to make a 10:90 split in the entire table and add another column with a test-train label, while keeping the class balance intact. So, if there is any other better way to do this, please suggest.

(I do realise that python could make life easier, but I wish to know if we can do it with SQL directly, also kinda constrained to SQL at the moment.)

| Original Tweet | Sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| New Yorkers encounter empty supermarket shelves ... | Extremely Negative |
| When I couldn't find hand sanitizer at Fred Meyer, I turned ... | Positive |
| Find out how you can protect yourself and loved ones from ... | Extremely Positive |
| #Panic buying hits #NewYork City as anxious shoppers stock up on... | Negative |
| #toiletpaper #dunnypaper #coronavirus #coronavirusaustralia ... | Neutral |
| Do you remember the last time you paid $2.99 a gallon for ... | Neutral |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sentiment order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

If you wanted to split the data into 90-10 groups randomly, I would probably recommend `ntile()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when ntile(10) over (order by rand() <= 9 then 'train' else 'test'
        end) as grp
from t;
```

Comment: The ntile() method was much more apt for the task. Thanks a lot!